# What is the other side of a head of a series

Tags: word-request

If I have a series (of orders, of programs..etc) the first element of that series is the "head", isn't it.

How do you call the last element?

For example say you have a series of orders.
And you want to express that the next order is going to be put after the last element of the series to be executed after that last order.

Comment: The tail. At least in Spain, we use both terms in Computer Science when we implement a queue.

Comment: If the first is the "head" then, it is very likely that the end of it is the "tail".

Comment: At the foot of the list is quite common.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Are you sure the foot of a list is the same as the last item? For me, the foot would be underneath the last item, containing additional info such as totals or VAT or whatever.

Comment: I think that is a footer.

Comment: In computer science, the last element in a list is usually called the tail (and the first is called the head).

Comment: You should add a usage example.